# laravel 5.2 Displaying related data in the view

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my controller I use eager loading to load all properties along with their related files and addresses:

```
  public function search_results(Request $request)
{


    $Properties = Property::with('Residential', 'File', 'addresses')->get();

    return view('result', ['results' => $Properties]);
}
```

and pass is straight onto the view. But in the view.blade.php how do I access this related data.

Here is an example of my view but it does not seem to work with regards to the related data.

```
     @forelse ($results as $result)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @foreach($result->File() as $file)
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/properties/{{$file->filename}}">
        </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>{{ $result->title }}</h3>
        <h4>Subheading</h4>
        <p>{{ $result->description }}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">View Property
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my property model:

```
  class Property extends Model
{


protected $table = 'properties';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'is_for_sale','available','title', 'description','price','date_available'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}


public function Residential()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Residential');
}

/**
 * The Addresses that belong to the properties.
 */
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Address');
}


public function File()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\File');
}
}
```

the File model

```
  class File extends Model
  {

protected $table = 'files';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'property_id', 'file_type_id','filename','system_filename', 'is-deleted'
];


public function Property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
}


public function File_Type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\File_types');
}
 }
```

What is the correct way to handle this type of related data in a view?

Comment: When you say "Here is an example of my view but it does not seem to work with regards to the related data.", what is not working? The display of the data? First trying to `dd($Properties)` and see what is getting sent to the view.

Comment: The properties object contains property attributes as it should and also an array called relations which has Residential', 'File' and 'addresses' objects in it. So it looks like its being sent to the view correctly. Whats not working for me is accessing the relations from inside the view. $result->title works and shows the title of the property but if I try to load the related files object I get a fatal error.

Comment: What I am asking is if I use eager loading the load list of objects and their related objects. How do you access those related objects from inside a blade template? Is $result->File() as $file correct?

Comment: I am still looking on my end. I just got caught up with work.I ran into the same issue as you using $model->relationMethod(). I believe $model->relatedModel is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For your

`@foreach($result->File() as $file)`

change it to

`@foreach($result->File as $file)`.

The `$result->File()` is loading the same relations as you are with your `search_results()` method in the controller.